# comparing std::vector to a raw value of the same type give error

Tags: c++, string, stdvector, assert

I was doing an exercise while I noticed this

this code work okay:

```
std::vector<std::string> x = { "st1", "st1" };
std::vector<std::string> y = { "st1", "st1" };
assert(x == y);
```

while this give me error when trying to compile it

```
std::vector<std::string> x = { "st1", "st1" };
assert(x == { "st1", "st1" });
```

I have no idea why is that the case, could someone explain why and how to force it to compile if there is way to do it.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error should have told you something along the line of "`{ "st1", "st1" }` has no type".

If you want to construct a second vector you need to call the constructor:

```
assert(x == std::vector<std::string>{ "st1", "st1" });
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler expects an expression in this line

```
assert(x == { "st1", "st1" });
```

but this record `{ "st1", "st1" }` is not an expression.

Also the initializer list can not be used as an operand of an expression with the equality operator == where other operand has the type `std::vector<std::string>`.

You could write for example

```
assert ( v == std::vector<std::string>( { "str1", "str1"  } ) );
```